# Is there a one-liner to unpack tuple/pair into references?

Tags: c++

I frequently write snippets like

```
int x,y,z; tie(x,y,z) = g[19];
```

where, for instance, `g` was declared earlier

```
vector<tuple<int,int,int>> g(100);
```

Problem is, maybe later I actually want `x` and `y` to point to the internals of `g` by reference, and the refactoring is ugly, e.g.

```
int &x = get<0>(g[19]);
int &y = get<1>(g[19]);
int &z = get<2>(g[19]);
```

or sometimes even worse, for instance if the access is a more complex expression

```
tuple<int,int,int> &p = g[19]; // if the rhs was actually more complicated
int &x = get<0>(p);
int &y = get<1>(p);
int &z = get<2>(p);
```

Is there a better refactoring, more in the style of the assignment to tie(..)?

The difficulty as I understand it is that references insist on being initialized [exactly at their declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization). So, in possibly other words, is there a way to use `tie`-like syntax for multiple variable *initialization* in c++ (this would also make the earlier non reference usage cleaner)?

Comment: Interesting, but I guess it's about time for you to define a named struct to replace tuple<int, int, int> ...

Comment: There is this paper: https://isocpp.org/files/papers/P0144R1.pdf (dunno if a more recent version exists)

Comment: Fair enough. But refactoring the tuple into a named struct both adds a name to the global namespace (unless we play more games, which to me makes the intent less clear, not more), and removes other conveniences to tuple, such as a default operator< .

Comment: @Hiura: [wg21.link/p0144](http://wg21.link/p0144) for the latest revision. [P0217](http://wg21.link/p0217) contains the wording.

Comment: @KerrekSB thanks for the links!

Comment: @Hiura: Don't get your hopes up just yet, the proposal is somewhat controversial. Watch out for news in the next few weeks.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Fortunately, C++17 has a solution for exactly this problem, the [structured binding declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding). Even the non-reference interface can be improved.

```
auto[x, y, z] = g[i];
```

The above line declares x, y,z and initializes them with the values of `g[i]`. Not only is it cleaner, but it could be more efficient for types that are expensive to construct.

To get references to the members of `g[i]`, one can write

```
auto& [x, y, z] = g[i];
```

Comment: @StevenVascellaro The two lines I wrote (after fixing the typo of using parentheses instead of brackets) are an example of how a structured binding declaration would be used to get the values or references out of an `std::tuple<int, int, int>`. The page I linked to also has 3 examples with comprehensive explanations. I can't come up with a better example for this. Is there something in particular you find confusing in my answer?

Comment: Do x, y, and z need to be declared and assigned values individually?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro They do not. This is the whole point of this feature. They are declared and initialized in a single line. eg in  the first example, `x` has been declared and copy-constructed from the first element of `g[i]`.

Comment: So if I wanted to initialize a set of integers, would I do something like `int num[3] = {1, 2, 3}; auto[x, y, z] = num;`?

Comment: @Stevoisiak In case you didn't get an answer to this and to provide closure, yes that works.

Answer (score 7):

You can automate it with a function so that you don't have to type out 3 (or more) lines:

```
template <class... Ts, std::size_t... Is, class Tuple>
decltype( auto ) tie_from_specified( std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple& tuple )
{
    return std::tuple<Ts...>{ std::get<Is>( tuple )... };
}

template <class... Ts, class Tuple>
decltype( auto ) tie_from( Tuple& tuple )
{
    return tie_from_specified<Ts...>( std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...( Ts )>{}, tuple );
}
```

Usage would be:

```
int x{ 2 };
std::tuple<int, int&, int> g19( 1, x, 3 );

// new tuple: ref to get<0>( g19 ), value of get<1>( g19 ), ref to get<2>( g19 )
auto t0{ tie_from<int&, int, int&>( g19 ) };

// new tuple: ref to get<0>( g19 ), ref to get<2>( g19 )
auto t1{ tie_from_specified<int&, int&>( std::index_sequence<0, 2>{}, g19 ) };
```

Comment: This seems to be the best solution in the meantime given the current standard. We'll see what the future holds with C++17.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a struct to store the references:

```
struct vector3d
{
    vector3d(std::tuple<int, int, int>& tuple)
      : x(std::get<0>(tuple)),
        y(std::get<1>(tuple)),
        z(std::get<2>(tuple))
    {}

    int& x;
    int& y;
    int& z;
};
```

And then use it like this:

```
vector3d vec(g[6]);
// do sth with vec.x or vec.y or vec.z or all together :)
```