# One liner tuple/pair unpack in c++ with reusing same variable multiple times

Tags: c++, c++17, std-pair

I have already seen [Is there a one-liner to unpack tuple/pair into references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876288/is-there-a-one-liner-to-unpack-tuple-pair-into-references) and know how the unpack values from tuple/pairs in a single line like following

```cpp
auto [validity, table] = isFieldPresentAndSet(r, "is_federated");
```

here `isFieldPresentAndSet` returns a tuple.

Now I want to reuse these two variable in multiple successive calls of `isFieldPresentAndSet` like following

```cpp
auto [validity, table] = isFieldPresentAndSet(r, "is_federated");
auto [validity, table] = isFieldPresentAndSet(r, "gslb_sp_enabled");
```

and then check the value for the `validity` and `table`. But this gives me compile error because I am redefining the `validity` and `table` variable second time. If the change the second line to

```cpp
[validity, table] = isFieldPresentAndSet(r, "gslb_sp_enabled");
```

or

```cpp
validity, table = isFieldPresentAndSet(r, "gslb_sp_enabled");
```

It still gives me compile error.

Is there any way to do this??

Comment: add {} around the block to make the vars local to that scope?

Comment: Nope. I have to put both tuple unpacking into separate scope. But the checking after calling the function would happen outside.

Comment: `std::tie(validity, table) = isFieldPresentAndSet(r, "gslb_sp_enabled"); `?

Comment: Unclear to me because that means you unpack multiple times and check once???

Comment: @Klaus yes that's what I am doing

Comment: structured_binding is C++17 though, tags fixed.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes I could use tie but I was looking for more cleaner solution. Thanks though!

Comment: If you check once, you get only the result of last unpacking... really? :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie). It returns a tuple of references, which makes the assignement possible:

```
std::tie(validity, table) = isFieldPresentAndSet(r, "gslb_sp_enabled");
```